# Proper way of transforming 3D primitives in C#/XNA?

Tags: c#, 3d, matrix, xna

I have a Block class that basically contains an array of 36 vertices, a constructor that builds the block around the origin (0, 0, 0), and a method for updating.

I'm using a Physics library to manipulate the blocks.  I assign a body and collision skin to the block and update the physics step every update.  After every update I get a matrix back with the block's new position, orientation, etc.

Now, what I can't wrap my head around is the best way to go about applying the matrix to the block and efficiently updating the vertex buffer every frame.

This is basically what I have at the moment, I'm almost positive there's a better method...

```
class Block
{
    const float FullBlockSize = 20f;
    const float HalfBlockSize = FullBlockSize / 2;

    public VertexPositionNormalTexture [] vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[36];
    public VertexPositionNormalTexture [] currentVertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[36];
    public DynamicVertexBuffer vBuffer;

    Vector3 position;

    public Block(Vector3 blockPosition)
    {
        position = blockPosition * FullBlockSize;

        /*
         * Build the 6 faces of the block here.
         * The block is built around the origin,
         * (0, 0, 0) being the center of the block.
        */

        vBuffer = new DynamicVertexBuffer(Game.Device, VertexPositionNormalTexture.VertexDeclaration, vertices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        vBuffer.SetData(vertices);
    }
    public Matrix WorldMatrix
    {
        get
        {
            return Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
        }
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        currentVertices = (VertexPositionNormalTexture[])vertices.Clone();
        Matrix currentWorld = WorldMatrix;
        for(int i = 0; i < currentVertices.Length; ++i)
        {
            currentVertices[i].Position = Vector3.Transform(currentVertices[i].Position, currentWorld);
        }
        vBuffer.SetData(currentVertices);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to modify the vertex data? This will get very slow. Storing the original vertices and the transform matrix is completely sufficient.

Comment: @NicoSchertler That's what I thought but it doesn't seem like passing the transform matrix to the GPU and drawing the triangles is working.  They're all just stuck at the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the shader do it...one of the parameters of a shader is usually a WorldMatrix...

to draw it:

```
effect.Parameters["WorldMatrix"].SetValue(World);
effect.Apply(0);
```

if you have problems drawing a block... try to create a world transform matrix by yourself and test it...

```
effect.Parameters["WorldMatrix"].SetValue(Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angle));
effect.Apply(0);
```

If you have several instances of block, you can use instancing to pass the trasnform matrix in a vertexBuffer to the shader...

Here you can find info about instancing:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/17/drawinstancedprimitives-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Comment: In your first statement, do you mean to set the world matrix of the shader to the cube's transform, draw it, repeat until all cubes are drawn?

The instancing sounds nice, but it sounds like more of a performance concern (correct me if I'm wrong).  For now I'd just like to focus on getting the basics down of actually getting multiple cubes on the screen.

I now have a Draw() method which sets the shader's world matrix to the cube's transform, and then draws it.  This doesn't seem to have any affect (all of the cubes are drawn on the origin).

Comment: Then you're either passing the wrong world matrix or the shader's not proper... Figure it out or post a new question regarding that.